# Different themes for different languages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I've tried searching for the answer to this but am coming up blank.

In sublime text, it's possible to have different themes for different file types as specified in the preferences file. For example, you can have a light coloured theme for Markdown/Plain text files and a normal Monokai type theme for all other languages. I find this very useful as I prefer to have different fonts and settings when typing compared to when coding.

As far as I can see, this functionality isn't present in VSCode. Am I wrong or is there a way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's now possible to do using an extension called "Theme by language" from Julien Saulou. It can be downloaded from [Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsaulou.theme-by-language).

Comment: It's disappointing that this treats *ipynb and *py files as the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, there is no way to do that.

You can however, define different themes (color and icon) for each **workspace** (`Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`). It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it may be useful if your different languages are located/related in different workspaces.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20652