# customize color theme for a file type or a specific extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I m looking for a way to setup a **specific color theme** (or alter the default color theme)

```
based on the type of file edited by vs code
```

OR

```
depending on the used extension
```

I've read HOW TO setup a color theme and alter the default color theming but I could not find HOW TO setup a specific rendering based on file type. It seems the theme apply to the whole application. More specifically what I m interested in is to use say the "Light" color theme rendering while editing **drawio file** (graphical file edited using a dedicated extension) and use the "Dark" theme rendering for code editing (any other file type).
The extension I use refer to appropriate color theme and finally what might a good option would be to set a given color theme based on the extention involved to edit the file but that might require to dig into the extension source code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different themes for different languages in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263971/different-themes-for-different-languages-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @jolammi applying the described command does change the theme but it is applied to all windows irrespective of what is being edited (in my context md , python and drawio files). Here what I did : CTRL - SHIFT - P "set theme for current file language" but there is no way to pass a theme !